# How to copy s3 data from aws account1 to aws account2 using boto3 and assume_role?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm working on a use case where I need to copy data from AWS S3 in account1(region1) to AWS S3 in account2(region2). For doing this a have created a lambda function using `boto3` and `assume_role()` in account1 which will write to AWS S3 in account2.

So the destination bucket in account2 has below bucket policy defined -

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                },
                "ForAllValues:StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:TlsVersion": [
                        "1.2",
                        "1.3"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::<account1-id>:role/cross-account-file-share-role"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:Put*",
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:Delete*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In account1 `cross-account-file-share-role` trust policy looks like this -

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:sts::<account1-id>:assumed-role/<my-lambda-role>/<my-lambda>",
                    "arn:aws:iam::<account1-id>:role/FullResourceAccessforEC2"
                ],
                "Service": [
                    "lambda.amazonaws.com",
                    "s3.amazonaws.com",
                    "storagegateway.amazonaws.com",
                    "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

The `lambda` I wrote to do this copy activity looks like this -

```
def lambda_handler(event, context, destination_bucket=destination_bucket, destination_bucket_path=destination_bucket_path):
    
    source_bucket = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    source_bucket_path = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    
    print(source_bucket)
    print(source_bucket_path)
    
    sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
    
    assumed_role_object = sts_client.assume_role(
        RoleArn=f'{role_arn}',
        RoleSessionName=f'{role_session_name}',
        DurationSeconds=900
        )
        
    ACCESS_KEY = assumed_role_object['Credentials']['AccessKeyId']
    SECRET_KEY = assumed_role_object['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey']
    SESSION_TOKEN = assumed_role_object['Credentials']['SessionToken']
    
    s3_client = boto3.client(
        's3',
        region_name = 'us-west-2',
        aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
        aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN
        )

    s3_client.copy_object(Bucket=destination_bucket, CopySource={'Bucket':source_bucket,'Key':source_bucket_path}, Key=destination_bucket_path)
```

However, I'm getting below error -

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CopyObject operation: The ciphertext refers to a customer master key that does not exist, does not exist in this region, or you are not allowed to access.",
  "errorType": "ClientError",
  "requestId": "<request id>",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 41, in lambda_handler\n    s3_client.copy_object(Bucket=destination_bucket, CopySource={'Bucket':source_bucket,'Key':source_bucket_path}, Key=destination_key)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 530, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 960, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}
```

Not sure what access permissions are missing here. Please help.

Comment: Did you try without the `Deny` policy?

Comment: No I don't have permission to make changes to bucket policy.

Comment: So how do you know that the policy is correct, because I suspect this Deny.

Comment: I checked with the Admins they said its correct only. I'm suspecting some additional steps needs to be added in my `lambda`. Do you see anything there?

Answer (score 2):

The `ciphertext` error message normally indicates that there is a default encryption key on the destination bucket and you do not have permission to use it.

You should ask the bucket owner for the ARN of the KMS key that should be used, and then specify it as part of the `copy_object()` command using:

```py
    s3_client.copy_object(
        Bucket=destination_bucket,
        CopySource={'Bucket':source_bucket,'Key':source_bucket_path}, 
        Key=destination_bucket_path
        ServerSideEncryption='aws:kms',
        SSEKMSKeyId=ARN-TO-USE
    )
```

They might need to add permissions to the KMS Key to permit your role to use the KMS Key.

You can **test which bucket is causing the error** by attempting to access each of them seperately:

```py
    print('Trying to read source object')
    response = s3_client.get_object(
        Bucket=source_bucket,
        Key=source_bucket_path
    )

    print('Trying to write destination object')
    s3_client.put_object(
        Bucket=destination_bucket,
        Key=destination_bucket_path,
        Body='Test',
        # ServerSideEncryption='aws:kms',
        # SSEKMSKeyId=kms_key,
    )
```

Comment: Tried this option as well but getting the same error as mentioned in my post. Do you see any other modification?

Comment: Are you sure that the IAM Role you are using has permission to use the KMS Key? It would be configured on the KMS Key itself.

Comment: The `ciphertext` error is either referring to the source bucket (where your role does not have permission to use a KMS key) or the destination bucket (where your role does not have permission to use a KMS key). You should try to figure out which one is causing the error. I have added some sample code for you to figure out whether the error is being caused by reading from the Source bucket or writing to the Destination bucket.

Comment: Yes in the `get_object()` I'm getting this error. `put_object()` worked fine.

Comment: The IAM Role that you are assuming with `assume_role()` apparently doesn't have permission to use the KMS key that was used to encrypt the object.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, will check with the bucket owner now. Other than that do you feel like anything else is missing in the implementation?

Comment: Only testing will reveal if something else is missing.

Comment: The missing piece was to add the lambda role to the kms key role. Because of that I was getting the error. Now after resolving that I'm getting timed out exception within 4secs of running it. I tried adding duration seconds as 2000 as well but same issue. Can we resolve that not sure what's the issue?

Comment: Please provide the _exact_ error and describe where you saw the error and what line triggered it. You are welcome to Edit your question and add additional detail (but leave the original question as-is).